# Optional Route path that matches a certain string or is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to make use of a Router path that matches `/client` and `client/upload` exactly in order to `Redirect` my component properly. I know that in order to write an optional param you would write it like

```
<Redirect exact from={`${match.path}(/:id)?`} to={`${match.url}/upload/view`} />
```

But now I want my path param to be only restricted to upload so I write it like

```
<Redirect exact from={`${match.path}/:id(|upload)`} to={`${match.url}/upload/view`} />
```

which redirects from '/client/upload' and `${match.path}/` to `${match.path}/upload/view` properly but doesn't work with `${match.path}`.

I have also tried `${match.path}(/:id(|upload))?`, `${match.path}/?:id(|upload)'`, `${match.path}(/upload)?` but none of them work

I would like `${match.path}`, `${match.path}/` and `${match.path}/upload` to redirect to `'${match.url}/upload/view`.

For now I am writing two different Redirects like

```
<Redirect exact from={match.path} to={`${match.url}/upload/view`} />
<Redirect exact from={`${match.path}/upload`} to={`${match.url}/upload/view`} />
```

but I would really like to write only one `Redirect`.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What about `<Redirect exact from='/client(/upload)?' to='/client/upload/view' />`?

Comment: @HridayModi  Tried this too, did not work out, Not sure why. According to my understanding this should have worked. This is when I tried out `'/client/:id(|upload)'` which is the closest that I got

Comment: Can you try removing `exact` keyword? I also wrote it by mistake.

Comment: If I remove the exact keyword, routes like `/client/upload/element` will also match, won't they

Comment: Yes it would match!

Comment: @HridayModi, which is why I have the exact keyword, to avoid redirection from such routes

Comment: Yes Solution in first comment works like charm. Check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1ok0lywjkq)

Comment: @HridayModi, Well yes it does work in the codepen demo. The problem seem to come because I was using `${match.path}(/upload)?`, using `${match.url}(/upload)?` worked for some reason. You can post it as an answer if you want

Comment: It may be depending on your use case. Anyway have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Redirect exact from='/client(/upload)?' to='/client/upload/view' />
```

This should solve your problem as it says that exact `/client` and `/client/upload` matches and will be redirected to the path defined in *to* parameter.